# CarrierWave and multiple uploaders to store files based on a specific model's permalink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

Can someone please assist with regards to CarriveWave's store_dir.

How does one have mulitple image models that stores files based on the associated belong_to model's permalink?

```
# Garage model
class Garage < ActiveRecord:Base

  attr_accessible: :avatar, :permalink, :car_image_attributes,
                   :motorcycle_image_attributes

  has_many :car_image
  has_many :motorcycle_image

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def set_permalink
    self.permalink = permalink.parameterize
  end

  def to_param
    permalink.parameterize
  end

end
```

This is what my Image Models that links with CarrierWave

```
# Car Image model
CarImage < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :garage
  attr_accessible: :garage_id, :image

  mount_uploader :car_image, CarUploader

end

# Motocycle Image model
MotocycleImage < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :garage
  attr_accessible: :garage_id, :image

  mount_uploader :motorcycle_image, MotocycleUploader

end
```

This is what my CarrierWave uploaders look like.

```
# CarrierWave avatar uploader
avatar_uploader.rb
  # This uploader directly relates to the Garage model table 
  # column avatar:string.

  def store_dir
    # This works for the avatar because it calls on the Garage permalink
    # but it fails for the other image models because it's a model relation
    # has_many, belongs_to and the model.permalink will be based on the
    # uploader's respective model and not the Garage model
    # eg. car_uploader.rb = model.permalink = CarImage.permalink
    # I would like it to refer to to Garage.permalink at all times.
    "garage/#{model.permalink}/#{mounted_as}/"
  end
end

# CarrierWave car and motorcycle uploaders
car_uploader.rb
# Fails to upload because it doesn't know what permalink is
end

motorcycle_uploader.rb
# Fails to upload because it doesn't know what permalink is
end
```

Apologies if I wants so clear but a big thanks for any insight given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the easiest way would be to delegate the permalink to the parent on the model

```
CarImage < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :garage
  delegate : permalink, :to => :garage
  attr_accessible: :garage_id, :image

  mount_uploader :car_image, CarUploader



end
```

Comment: Thank you Yuriy for the happiness. Thank you for exposing the delegate class method to me and how useful it is for ActiveRecord associations.